# Inbuilt mic input volume very low on macOS Monterey though set to max

Tags: macos, microphone

I am using a MacBook Air 13 inch 2017 model with macOS Monterey 12.7.3. This is the latest OS for my device.
I recently came to know about a problem with the input mic of my device when people started complaining during online meetings. I am not sure when it started, but it wasn't there a few months back.

In System Preferences -> Sound, the input device is built in input microphone. The input volume level is set to maximum. However, when I speak normally or even louder than normally, the input level indicator goes up to 2-3 bars. If I am really shouting, it is going up to 5 bars.

However, if I reduce the input volume and bring it to the middle, the input level just remains zero.

This issue is not there when I attach an earphone with a mic. Even when the input volume is at the middle, the input level easily goes up.

Can you please help resolve this? I badly hope this is a software issue.micr

Answer (score 0):

Your Mic is located on the left side of the Mac.

It is a very small (like pinhole) at about the hight of the shift key.

Slide your finger over the hole and the Mic indicator should go to 100.

If not blow it out with can off air, do not stick metal objects in it. When using make sure it is not blocked.

Comment: Thanks to you I can locate the mic. Sliding my finger over it indeed takes the mic indicator/input level to 100%. Why then is my input voice so low?

Comment: @damaihati if your problems are with Zoom meetings, check this out https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0064198

Comment: No, the problem is not only with zoom. It is a general problem with mic. I have tested using Voice Memos app.

Comment: @damaihati OK then try in Safe mode to exclude any non Apple apps doing it. Reboor and Hold Shift (⇧): Start up in safe mode.

Comment: In safe mode, the inbuilt mic level option is greyed out. This is a general feature of safe mode. In addition, my voice memo app is crashing every time I press record button in safe mode!

Comment: @damaihati I did not know that, now I do, what Voice memo app are you using

Comment: I am using the voice memo app by Apple that comes pre-installed on Mac. This app is crashing when I try to record only in safe mode. This doesn’t happen in normal mode.

Comment: @damaihati thank you for the info. I am just trying to find out if you have another audio app that would create the problem with Mic volume been to low

Comment: No, I do not have any other audio app. Additionally, this problem wasn’t there earlier and I don’t remember installing any new app other than WhatsApp.